# spring mvc static resources failed to load

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, static-resource

I am trying to use static resources in my sample spring mvc project, In my project I have created a theme under resources folder as shown in the picture.[image]

Then I have added the following 3 lines of code in spring-mvc-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd  
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd  
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.sudheer.example" />

   <context:annotation-config />

   <bean
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

       <property name="prefix">
           <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
       </property>

       <property name="suffix">
           <value>.jsp</value>
       </property>        

   </bean>

   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/theme/" cache-period="31556926"/>
   <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />   

</beans>
```

WhenI try to access the static resources in many differnt ways,I am not able to access it.
This is my jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="/resources/themes/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/themes/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/themes/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>" 
rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>1. Test CSS</h1>
    <h2>2. Test JS</h2>
    <div class="btn"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

You have 3 problems:

- 1: In your Maven project, the folder `src/main/resources` has a special meaning for Maven: its content will be put in the classpath after compiling.
- 2: when you use spring resources mapping then the part of the url that mapping that match the mapping part '**' will been added to the location part for obtaining the file. *(sorry for the bad explanation)* An example will make it more clear: assume you have this resource mapping

  ```
   <mvc:resources mapping="/a/**" location="/b/c/" >
  ```

  And you request the url `http://localhost/myApp/a/d` then spring will look for the file at `/b/c/d`! - So when you send an request for `....../resources/themes/css/bootstrap.min.css` Spring would search for: `/resources/theme/themes/css/bootstrap.min.css`
- 3: in spring config and folder you use `theme` but in the jsp you use `themes`

---

Solution for **1** would be: either you change the `location` spring resource mapping to pick up the resource from classpath by using `classpath:` prefix in location attribute or you put your files in an other folder: `source/main/webapp/resources/theme` (then the location parameter `/resources/theme/`) would map.

example with classpath fix for **1** and one possible fix for **2**:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/theme/**"
    location="classpath:/resources/theme/" cache-period="31556926"/>
```

jsp - fix for **3**:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/theme/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>" 
       rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably is this:

You have this configuration

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/theme/"
```

But when you call the resourcek, you use this

```
<c:url value="/resources/themes/css/bootstrap.min.css"/
```

i htink you have to use this

```
/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Answer (score 1):

If a resource need visible by a frontend, you need put the resources in "webapp" folder. Example: webapp/theme/css/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 1):

I have create a skeleton project for Spring MVC (static resources are used also) [here](https://github.com/hussembadri/SpringMVC_Skeleton).